# Deserialize only specific Nodes from Xml to Object

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I am trying to take specific Nodes from an Xml and write it into a class. I have this.

```
public class TradeMark
{
    [XmlElement]
    public string MarkVerbalElementText { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public int MarkCurrentStatusCode { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public string ExpiryDate { get; set; } = ""; 
}
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TradeMark));
        using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(pathToImportFile))
        {
            tradeMark = (TradeMark)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
```

In my Xml Data, there are more Node than just these 3. Now when i run the Code it says ...... was not expected. I guess bc. It tries to deserialize everything than only these 3 Infomartionen in Class TradeMark.

Can anyone help?

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Transaction xmlns="http://euipo.europa.eu/trademark/data" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://euipo.europa.eu/trademark/data http://euipo.europa.eu/schemas/trademark/EM-TM-TradeMark-V3-2.xsd">
<TransactionHeader>
        <SenderDetails>
            <RequestProducerDateTime>2018-08-18T15:33:35</RequestProducerDateTime>
        </SenderDetails>
    </TransactionHeader>
<TradeMarkTransactionBody>
<TransactionContentDetails>
<TransactionIdentifier>017690538</TransactionIdentifier>
<TransactionCode>EM-Trade Mark</TransactionCode>
<TransactionData>
<TradeMarkDetails>
<TradeMark operationCode="Insert">
<RegistrationOfficeCode>EM</RegistrationOfficeCode>
<ApplicationNumber>017690538</ApplicationNumber>
<ApplicationDate>2018-01-16</ApplicationDate>
<RegistrationDate>2018-06-14</RegistrationDate>
<ApplicationLanguageCode>en</ApplicationLanguageCode>
<SecondLanguageCode>es</SecondLanguageCode>
<ExpiryDate>2028-01-16</ExpiryDate>
<MarkCurrentStatusCode milestone="23" status="1">Registered</MarkCurrentStatusCode>
<MarkCurrentStatusDate>2018-06-15</MarkCurrentStatusDate>
<KindMark>Individual</KindMark>
<MarkFeature>Figurative</MarkFeature>
<TradeDistinctivenessIndicator>false</TradeDistinctivenessIndicator>
<WordMarkSpecification>
<MarkVerbalElementText>Tiens</MarkVerbalElementText>
</WordMarkSpecification>
```

Comment: Can you post the exact error? Also, can you post the full XML? It could be malformed.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this happens because your XML has a default namespace and `Transaction` is within this namespace.
You need to mark your class with `XmlRootAttribute` like so:

```
[XmlRootAttribute("TradeMark", Namespace="http://euipo.europa.eu/trademark/data", 
IsNullable = false)]
public class TradeMark
```

Comment: Does not make any difference, Still the same Exception

Answer (score 0):

`XmlIgnore` is what you're looking for.

[MSDN Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributes.xmlignore?view=netframework-4.7.2)

See clarification in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2350480/1717855) answer, as the docs only state `XmlIgnore` will be ignored on serialize, but will also be ignored when deserializing.

From your example:

```cs
public class TradeMark
{
    [XmlElement]
    public string MarkVerbalElementText { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public int MarkCurrentStatusCode { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public string ExpiryDate { get; set; } = ""; 
    [XmlIgnore]
    public string IgnoreMe { get; set; } // This will be ignored
}
```